# AngularFire2 Microsoft Auth delivers POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion 400

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I try to implement Sign-In with Microsoft in Firebase via angularfire2.
Google Sign-In went well with:

```
 return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      provider.addScope('profile');
      provider.addScope('email');
      this.afAuth
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(res => {

          resolve(res);
        })
    })
```

Now I'm trying Microsoft Sign-In with

```
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      let provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
      firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)

        .then((result) => {
          console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result))
          resolve(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Handle error.
        });
    })
```

But it just delivers an error:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=AIzaS.... 400
```

I set up the Microsoft Authentication with this tutorial:
https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/adding-microsoft-authentication-using-firebase-485f0bd1e3eb

Am I'm missing something in my function or how does the Microsoft Sing-In work?

Answer (score 0):

According to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

You've to import the "value" of the client secret into firebase, which is only shown once. Unfortunately I pasted the "secret ID" to the firebase "App-Secret".